# How to show the same string from list into another activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-adapter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm fetching/retrieving some data from `Firebase` and showing it in my app using [FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter).

The data is getting retrieved successfully and is getting shown in `FastAdapter`.

Here is a snapshot of the data fetched:

[image]

I am using `putExtra()` and sending the string above, i.e, "help me out" and "666777" to another activity and showing these string in that activity.

The problem is that upon clicking the above item, i.e., the item having "help me out" string, the string which is getting shown in another activity is "666777".

Here's how I have implemented `FastAdapter.OnClickListener<>()`

```
fastItemAdapter.withOnClickListener(new FastAdapter.OnClickListener<HelpRequest>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClick(View v, IAdapter<HRequest> adapter, HRequest item, int position) {
                Intent hRequestExtendedIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HRequestExtended.class);
                hRequestExtendedIntent.putExtra("hDescription", hDescription);
                startActivity(hRequestExtendedIntent);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Here's how I'm fetching data from Firebase:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://appName-e8a12.firebaseio.com/");

databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map<String, String> newRequest = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                //hDescription has two different values in database
                hDescription = newRequest.get("hDescription");

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

What I want is I want to show the respective string on which the user has clicked. For ex- if the user clicked on "help me out" one then in the next activity the string "help me out" should be shown.

I have no idea how to do that, please let me know.

Comment: how are you setting the `hDescription`?

Comment: Is this a typo or? Once you're using `hRequestExtendedIntent` and you're using `putExtra` on `helpRequestExtendedIntent`. Those are two different intents (or a typo)

Comment: At first glance...it seems your variable "hDescription" is storing the inforation from the last item of the list. Please could you provide the code where you assign any value to this variable? Thanks

Comment: @Vucko yeah, it was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: Did that typo fix anything or was it just an unimportant thing? If it didn't fix it, please show the code where `hDescription` is being given a value.

Comment: @Vucko no, typo didn't fixed anything. please see the edited question.

Comment: @Nerd please see the edited question

Comment: @Nerd are you going to help with this?